ImOnline Pallet Migration Causing Storage Root Mismatch
my name is Jimmy and I am a member of the Gossamer team at ChainSafe Systems. We are building a Golang implementation of the Polkadot host and are currently using Paseo as one of the networks to test our node.
When syncing Paseo, I have run into an interesting situation at block 1789153 where the root we calculate differs from the expected root. This is associated with upgrading the spec to version 1002004. From my investigation, it appears our issue has to do with the ImOnline Pallet migration.
When I execute this block against the previous state I get the following logs:

If you compare my logs to the reference logs found here, you will notice that in our execution we find one key associated with the ImOnline pallet and remove it, while the reference logs have the "No ImOnline keys found post-removal " log.
I check which host calls use a key from this pallet, as you can see in the logs in my output above. In order, there is a call to NextKey(), then Set(), and then ClearPrefix(). The interesting thing is that if I block the Set() call of the key associated with the ImOnline pallet, the root is calculated correctly. Given that a) the reference logs don't indicate that this insertion occurs (since no keys are removed after) and b) removing the insertion fixes our issue, this seems to point to the issue being the Set call. I am trying to figure out the context around this problem and determine where it is coming from.
I have spent time digging through this runtime upgrade, the ImOnline Migration logic, and the migration logic for other pallets that get migrated in this block, but I have had no luck finding where this insertion might be coming from in the runtime.
It's also worth noting we do not encounter this issue on westend, it only happens on paseo.
I am hoping that someone might be able to give some context around the migration or shed some light on where this insertion could potentially be coming from. Any help would be greatly appreciated 

Did you also check the logs when syncing with the Parity node? The try-runtime-cli can behave slightly different and omits the state root check in the block finalization, so it would not error here even if it did differ.
